# n pages of changes IS vs n pages of changes ARE

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Should it be:

> 6 pages of changes **is** certainly copious

or

> 6 pages of changes **are** certainly copious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to refer to the groups of items *individually* or *collectively*.  For example:

> The six herds of elephants **are** heading toward the river.

This suggests that each of the herds is moving separately, but in a coordinated way.  However we could collectively refer to the total number of elephants as a singular value:

> Six herds of elephants **is** a lot of elephants.

In your example, it sounds like you are talking about the collective set of pages/changes, in which case the verb should also be singular:

> Six pages of changes **is** certainly a copious (bordering on the ridiculous) amount of changes.

However if you follow by referring to the *action* related to each of the changes, you could use the plural:

> How are we expected to get through **all those** in a single day?

Or you could again refer to them collectively:

> How are we expected to get through **all that** in a single day?

Comment: I particularly like your "follow-up" illustration contrasting ***all those*** and ***all that*** (both of which can be *equally and perfectly natural,* even though we'd have quite a strong preference for *singular* in the preceding statement as provided by OP).